# Delete key press event in Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have a date picker control (Datetimepicker for Bootstrap 3 * version : 4.15.35), in which I have added a required field validator. I want to check if the user uses the delete key to delete the date. If yes,and if there is no value in datepicker i want to show a validation message. I have added a validation message, but it works only when backspace key is pressed and the data is removed. Below is the existing code:

In Index.cshtml

```
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">
    <form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate="">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="control-label">Start date</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="startDatepicker">
                    <input type="text" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-model="defaultStartDate" name="startDate">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.startDate.$error.required">Start Date is required</span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitted=true" />
    </form>
</div>
```

In controller.js:

```
var setDefaultDate = new Date();
    $scope.defaultStartDate = moment(setDefaultDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');


    jQuery('#startDatepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        defaultDate: new Date()
    });

    jQuery('#startDatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate($scope.defaultStartDate);


    jQuery("#startDatepicker").on("dp.change", function(e) {
        jQuery('#startDatepicker').focus();     

);
```

I have tried using the below code, to check if delete key is pressed, but the event is not invoked.

```
jQuery("#startDatepicker").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 46) {
            alert('Delete Key Pressed');
        }
    });
```

Is there any other way in AngularJs to identify if the data is empty (date removed through delete key press) ?
How to fix this? Thanks